# Find the current location of mobile without using the GPS

Tags: android, gps, location

I am developing an restaurant locator for that i need to find the current location of mobile without using the GPS, is it possible?

kindly help me with the codes

Comment: **-1** : Try to use more elaborative title of the questions and post more details or codes if you have done something before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` but why would one do that?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: Bro i m plannning to develop a resturant locator in android can u guide me?